# AWS Lambda Layer import for Python function

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I need to import the `pysftp` library for my `python3.6` lambda function.

I created the folder structure required, pip installed the library into the correct folder and zipped it. As far as I know, this should work, or did i miss smth.
Btw I created the layer.zip in an aws Linux ec2 and uploaded it from there.

But the lambda function just cant import the library. The Error message is:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function'"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more about the acutal lamba setup and code? Because it could also be that you set your lambda handler to be `lambda_function` but in code is actually something else

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
After setting everything up fresh I noticed I installed the libraries with pip instead of pip3. Just a minor misstype.